# Is it possible to select data in groups / arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a database which looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `enter_uniq_data` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` set('email','phone','website','address','custom_field') NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`type`),
  UNIQUE KEY `value` (`value`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It is used for `typeahead`. So is it possible thought one select get all data with defined user id so that it would be sorted by type or I can do it only by separate queries?

Answer (score 0):

If your unassigned IDs contain null, you can do this :

```
SELECT *
FROM enter_uniq_data
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY TYPE
```

Or, if your unassigned IDs contain 0, you can use this :

```
SELECT *
FROM enter_uniq_data
WHERE user_id != 0
ORDER BY TYPE
```

Comment: in this case i get only of one type, but i need get all types. For example in the same time there can by 2 phones, 3 emails and etc.

Comment: One type? This query obtains records of the enter_uniq_data table, what else do you want?

Comment: This will get all the records in the table, if the user_id exists.

Comment: yes, i know, but i need that this result would be already sorted by types. Something like `array('email' => result_of_email, 'phone' => result_of_phones, 'website' => result_of_websites....` So my question was is it possible to do on MySQL level or not.

Comment: MySQL will return you one line per record in the database, it won't prepare your arrays for you, you need to do that with PHP.